# Best practice to edit web.config of a web application?

Tags: web-config, blob-cache

I would like to build something in C# to edit the web.config of the web application.

I would like to enable the blob cache for the image renditions.

What is the best practice to edit the web.config **Programmatically**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  modify web.config settings is to use the [SPWebConfigModification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx) class of the Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration namespace, which allows you to dynamically register entities. These modifications are persisted in the configuration database where they function as a kind of virtual web.config that effectively serves as the final layer of the .config file stack for the SharePoint Foundation web application.

[How to: Add and Remove Web.config Settings Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909.aspx)

To enable Blob Cahce, please check this:

[Enabling Blob Cache programmatically](http://bramnuyts.be/2011/03/31/enabling-blob-cache-programmatically/)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the following for general guidelines around Blob configuration for media in sharepoint

1. [Caching Best practices in SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kunal_mukherjee/archive/2011/01/10/caching-in-share-point-2010-best-practice.aspx)
2. [Blob configuration steps in SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770229.aspx#BLOB)

This is pretty generic, but is a worthwhile read :  [Security Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdh19h94(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: I know how to enable the blob cache in the web.config manaul. I need to know now how to do that programmatically?

Comment: A basic search gave me this: http://bramnuyts.be/2011/03/31/enabling-blob-cache-programmatically/ You can try following the steps.